# How many number of ways seat can be arranged

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, combinations, dynamic-programming

I found following problem in one of the interviews. Please suggest me the algorithm for this. I don't need code.

There are `N` number of people and `N` number of seats in a Cinema hall.Every person has his preference list of seats like:

Person 1 -> 1, 2 , 4

Person 2 -> 2 , 5

Person 3 -> 1 , 3 and so on ..

I need to find the number of ways the seat can be arranged in stable order(This means that every person must get there seat from there preference list).

Comment: this question should not be posted on stackoverflow since it is not about coding

Comment: @wdetac sorry dear its about algorithm.

Comment: Any constraints? number of seat/person?

Comment: @PhamTrung seat/person can be up to 10^9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we translate your problem in the language of graphs, we obtain a [bipartite graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BipartiteGraph.html) where persons and seats represent two disjoint sets of vertices. What are you looking for is a number of perfect matchings in such graph.

I am surprised that you found that problem in interviews because it is a topic of serious scientific research. There are two papers that you should have a look on:

- [Finding all the perfect matchings in bipartite graphs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0893965994900450)
- [Algorithms for Enumerating All Perfect, Maximum and
  Maximal Matchings in Bipartite Graphs](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.107.8179&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

In short, first paper provides an algorithm to enumerate all perfect matchings in `O(c(n+m)+n^(2.5))` time, while second paper improves it and gives algorithm with `O(mn^(0.5)+ cn)` time, where `n` denotes the number of vertices, `m` denotes the number of edges, and `c` denotes the number of perfect matchings in the given bipartite graph.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class SeatArrangement{
        static int count = 0;
        static Set<Integer> hs = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();

        static void getArrangementCount(LinkedList<ArrayList<Integer>> ll, int persons, int person){
            ArrayList<Integer> al = ll.get(person);
            Iterator<Integer> itr = al.iterator();

            if(person == persons){
                while(itr.hasNext()){
                    int value = itr.next();
                    if(!hs.contains(value)){
                        hs.add(value);
                        System.out.println("Entries = " + hs);
                        count++;
                        hs.remove(value);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                while(itr.hasNext()){
                    int value = itr.next();
                    if(!hs.contains(value)){
                        hs.add(value);
                        getArrangementCount(ll, persons, person + 1);
                        hs.remove(value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            int []arr1 = {1, 2, 4};
            int []arr2 = {2, 5};
            int []arr3 = {1, 3};
            int persons = 3;
            LinkedList<ArrayList<Integer>> ll = new LinkedList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

            ArrayList<Integer> al1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++){
                al1.add(arr1[i]);
            }

            ArrayList<Integer> al2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 0; i<arr2.length; i++){
                al2.add(arr2[i]);
            }

            ArrayList<Integer> al3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 0; i<arr3.length; i++){
                al3.add(arr3[i]);
            }

            ll.add(al1);
            ll.add(al2);
            ll.add(al3);

            getArrangementCount(ll, persons-1, 0);
            System.out.println("Total Count = " + count);

        }
    }
```

Comment: It is recursive approach and scalable. If you want increase persons just add array of seat for that person and add it to ArrayList. Then add arrayList to LinkedList. Make sure persons are equals to total number of arrays added.

Comment: Thanks Aman for your time but would you just tell me the approach or a clear Algorithm that you used in the code.

Comment: Before increasing count I have printed entries of Set.
Entries = [1, 2, 3]
Entries = [1, 5, 3]
Entries = [2, 5, 1]
Entries = [2, 5, 3]
Entries = [4, 2, 1]
Entries = [4, 2, 3]
Entries = [4, 5, 1]
Entries = [4, 5, 3]
I have taken one elements from each array, If all number are distinct  then it will be a possible arrangement.

Comment: Aman please elaborate your algorithm,it does not make any sense.

Comment: 1 - Choose 1 from first array, now take 2 from second array, take 3 from third array(Can't take 1 as it is already in set) 
2 - Now take 5 from second array, and take 3 from third array(Can't take 1 as it is already in set)
 3 - Now take 2 from first array, 5 from second(can't take 2 as it is already in set), take 1 from third array.
 4 - Now take 2 from first array, 5 from second(can't take 2 as it is already in set), take 3 from third array
 so on

Answer (score 0):

These types of problems are solved with graphs. In that specific case, you have to represent everything with an undirected and unweighted bipartite graph (a simple bipartite graph). The vertices of the first partition are the people. The vertices of the second partition are the seats. The edges of the graph are the preferences of the people: lines that go from each person to the seats they want. The sets to be found are called maximal matchings (not "perfect", as said). Matching: set of disjoint edges (they don't share a vertex). Maximal: If another edge is added to the matching, it is distorted, because one or more of its vertices would be shared by several edges. In graphs there can be multiple maximal matchings.

Finding all the maximal matchings of a bipartite graph is not as easy as it seems. An effective and fast technique consists of resorting to the Monte Carlo Method:

We have a tail of edges. We start with an empty matching, add the first edge of the queue and block its vertices, that is, all other edges that affect one or both vertices of the edge added to the matching are blocked: they will be edges that we cannot add to the current matching. We jump to the next edge of the queue and ask if it's blocked. If it is, we ignore it. If it is not locked, we add it to the matching and lock it. We repeat the steps until we can no longer add edges to the match.

We will have to hash the matching to avoid repetitions. I won't explain how to do that, I don't think it's necessary.

Before filling another matching, we must unlock all the edges placed in the previous one. And now comes the most important thing: we must mess up the queue of edges, completely. For that the Durstenfeld and Fisher-Yates algorithms are very good (a bit faster than Knuth and Sattolo Cycle).

The halt condition can be any: maximum cycles, number of continuous repetitions, etc.

It's best to know the limits in advance. For example, in a 6x5 graph, it is impossible for there to be more than 720 maximal matchings. That amount is given by the equation known as the "binomial coefficient."

Comment: This sounds like chatgpt.  Are you aware, that it is often wrong ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Rohit Gupta: I am a researcher. I know very well what I'm talking about. I don't know why you mention ChatGPT, I guess you are a victim of paranoia about it. The problem raised in this thread is well solved in the way I suggested. If you don't understand it's not my problem.

Comment: In a week (or two!) I will upload the code of my Maximal Matcher algorithm, written in C, that does what I explained above. To adapt it you must have advanced knowledge, sorry. I'm still working on it: I'm building a neural network to precompute the iteration caps from the properties of the graph to be explored. The cap matrix will serve to optimize my algorithm for speed, although it's already fast without that optimization. PS: I will not respond to trolls or chatbots unrelated to the complex subject matter of this thread.

Comment: @SergioFisch thanks for answer. Could you please update the neural network code you were working on?

Comment: Sorry, the neural network idea didn't work. I spent a lot of time on it, but it's clear that a convolutional ANN cannot be trained to predict the number of matches in a bipartite graph. Now I am working on a matrix of empirical tops: I generate millions of random graphs and I count the matchings found in 10000 cycles. That data will then be packed into a static hash table, where each key is the encoding of a bipartite graph. Thus, for the "most probable" graphs there is already a precomputed statistical framework that can be used to limit the search for matchings.